# Posting Json from Unity to Node server reads incorrectly

Tags: node.js, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to connect my Unity game to my web server.  I connect to the server fine with a vue app and also tested the endpoints in Postman, which all work great.  However, when I send the JSON from Unity with the same information, it looks the same when I console out the req.body in my server route. Though when I get the length of the email, they are different.  Test@test.com has a length of 13, but when I send with Unity it has a length of 14.  It always adds an extra character (length).

LoginData.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class LoginData
{
    public string username;
    public string password;
}
```

SendData.cs

```
public void SendLogin()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Login());
    }

    private IEnumerator Login()
    {
        var email = loginEmail.text;
        var password = loginPassword.text;
        var loginData = new LoginData();
        loginData.username = loginEmail.text;
        loginData.password = loginPassword.text;
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(loginData);

        using UnityWebRequest webRequest = new UnityWebRequest(loginUrl, "POST");
        webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        byte[] rawJson = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        webRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(rawJson);
        webRequest.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        switch(webRequest.result)
        {
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.InProgress:
                Debug.Log("In Progress...");
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                Debug.Log(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                Debug.Log("Connection Error...");
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                Debug.Log("Protocol Error...");
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                Debug.Log("Data Processing Error...");
                break;
            default:
                Debug.Log("Default...");
                break;
        }

    }
```

Server output from Postman

```
req.body = { username: 'test@test.com', password: 'test' }
req.body.username.length = 13
```

Server output from Unity

```
req.body = { username: 'test@test.com​', password: 'test​' }
req.body.username.length = 14
```

Server Login Route

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
    let username = req.body.username;
    console.log('req.body = ' + req.body);
    console.log('req.body.username.length = ' + username.length);
    User.findOne({email: username})
    .then(async(user) => {
        if(!user) {
            console.log('not found');
            return res.status(401).send('Invalid Credentials.')
        }

        if (user.failedLoginAttempts >= allowedFailedLoginAttempts) {
            return res.status(401).send('Account Locked.')
        }

        const isValidPassword = await GSUtility.isValidPassword(req.body.password, user.password)

        if (isValidPassword) {
            console.log('good');
            const jwt = GSUtility.issueJWT(user);
            user.updateLogin();
            return res.status(200).send({ user: user, token: jwt.token, expires: jwt.expires })
        } else {
            user.increaseFailedLoginAttempts();
            console.log('bad info');
            return res.status(401).send('Invalid Credentials.')
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts from your server as well?

Comment: Sure thing.... added.  When sending from Unity it always fails at if(!user) on the server, so I am thinking the problem has to be from sending from Unity?

Comment: Could be interesting to print the length on the Unity side and the hex bytes of the string on both sides.

Comment: I'll give it a try and post it back... thanks!

Comment: So the length on the Unity side is reading the same @ 14.  The length of the JSON in Unity is 52, though server side it reads 48.  Since it is already parsed when I recieve it in the route I had to JSON.stringify the req.body, so that may have caused a drop in length if it strips any whitespace.

Comment: I have even JSON.stringify(), then JSON.parse() the req.body before grabbing the values to see if that would fix anything, but it was the same result as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the code you provided and a very minimal Node server, I cannot reproduce the issue you described.

I recommend checking if the issue still occurs when you manually hardcode the username/password values in the login data. I suspect the input field is adding a weird extra no-length whitespace character (or something like that) or that your issue is not actually between the client and the server but the actual values you are encoding in the first place.

You should also check and confirm how your server is handling body parsing, though I would suspect it is set up correctly if it's true that the request works fine from Postman. In the below example, I use the `body-parser` package, which works well.

Output from server:

```
Example app listening on port 3000
username.length: 13
{ username: 'test@test.com', password: 'pasword' }
```

Example node server:

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

app.use(jsonParser)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    console.log(`username.length: ${username.length}`)
    console.log({
        username,
        password
    })
    res.send({ message: 'success' })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Unity Script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

[Serializable]
public class LoginData
{
    public string username;
    public string password;
}

public class WebRequestTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SendRequest());
    }

    private IEnumerator SendRequest()
    {
        var loginUrl = "http://localhost:3000/login";
        var loginData = new LoginData();
        loginData.username = "test@test.com";
        loginData.password = "pasword";
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(loginData);

        using UnityWebRequest webRequest = new UnityWebRequest(loginUrl, "POST");
        webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        byte[] rawJson = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        webRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(rawJson);
        webRequest.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        switch(webRequest.result)
        {
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.InProgress:
                Debug.Log("In Progress...");
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                Debug.Log(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                Debug.Log("Connection Error...");
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                Debug.Log("Protocol Error...");
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                Debug.Log("Data Processing Error...");
                break;
            default:
                Debug.Log("Default...");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try, though I am not using body-parser I am using app.use(express.json());

I will see what happens if I hardcode the the json instead of using the Text inputs in Unity as well.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: LOL yes hardcoding works, so it must be something the input field is adding.... I should have known to check for that first... smh thanks for this!

Comment: If anyone has the same issue, this is how to get a TextMeshPro input the correct way... not the way I did it. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1562568/how-to-get-text-from-textmeshpro-input-field.html